# SKAction runAction does not execute completion block

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

A `SKSpriteNode` is child of a `SKNode` and is placed on an array of `SKSpriteNode` for storage purposes.

This `SKSpriteNode` is deleted using an animation. At the end of this animation a completion block is executed to perform some statements...

The deletion must occurred both in the `SKSpriteNode` parent’s and in the array. Depending on the order of these 2 deletions the result is correct or not:

- if `SKSpriteNode`is deleted from 1/ the array then 2/ from the `SKNode` parent’s, the completion block is executed.
- if the inverse order, 1/ `SKNode` parent’s then 2/ the array, the completion block is not executed.

Why this behavior?

```
for position in listOfPositions {

   theSprite:SKSpriteNode = theGrid[position]

   /// the SKSpriteNode referenced by theSprite :
   /// - belongs to an array of SKSpriteNode: theGrid
   /// - belongs to a SKNode: theGameLayer
   ///
   /// In other words this SKSpriteNode is referenced twice
   ///

   let theActions = SKAction.sequence([
      /// Some actions here
      /// ...

      /// Remove theSprite from the Grid
      /// - position is an instance of a structure of my own
      /// - theGrid is accessed via a subscript
      ///
      SKAction.runBlock({self.theGrid[position] = nil}),

      /// remove theSprite from it's parent
      SKAction.removeFromParent(),
   ])

   theSprite.runAction(theActions,completion:{NSLog("Deleted")})
}
```

The completion message is displayed.

Now if `removeFromParent` is placed before the remove from `theGrid` action, as follow, the completion does not execute:

```
let theActions = SKAction.sequence([
   /// Some actions here
   /// ...

   /// remove theSprite from it's parent
   SKAction.removeFromParent(),

   /// remove theSprite from the Grid
   SKAction.runBlock({self.theGrid[position] = nil}),
])
```

Comment: try this: SKAction.runBlock({self.theGrid[self.position] = nil}),

Comment: Adding `self` to `position`is not relevant in the situation: it leads to a compilation error.

Comment: i recommend to write self because i think it is like a scope problem.

Comment: Your recommendation is OK but does not apply to this situation as the scope for `position` is correct. It seems to be more related on how `removeFromParent` manage the execution of the completion block.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding explanations to better understand the context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [SKAction Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction):

> An SKAction object is an action that is executed by a node in the
>   scene (SKScene)...When the scene processes its nodes, actions associated with those
>   nodes are evaluated.

In other words, the actions for a node is run if and only if that node is in the scene. By calling `removeFromParent`, you remove the node from the scene, the `runBlock` action is never called (since the node is no longer in the scene), and thus the sequence is never finished. Since the sequence doesn't finish, the completion block doesn't get called.

I would suggest moving the `removeFromParent` call to the completion block for safety's sake. Something like this feels safer:

```
for position in listOfPositions {

   let theSprite: SKSpriteNode = theGrid[position]

   /// the SKSpriteNode referenced by theSprite :
   /// - belongs to an array of SKSpriteNode: theGrid
   /// - belongs to a SKNode: theGameLayer
   ///
   /// In other words this SKSpriteNode is referenced twice
   ///

   let theActions = SKAction.sequence([
      /// Some actions here
      /// ...

      /// Remove theSprite from the Grid
      /// - position is an instance of a structure of my own
      /// - theGrid is accessed via a subscript
      ///
      SKAction.runBlock({self.theGrid[position] = nil})
   ])

   theSprite.runAction(theActions) {
      /// remove theSprite from it's parent
      /// Might need to weakly reference self here
      theSprite.removeFromParent(),
      NSLog("Deleted")
   }
}
```

---

**TL;DR**
The sequence doesn't complete, so the completion block for sequence doesn't get called.

Comment: Although this code is a good improvement to mine, I am very septic on the explanation. Because 1/ the reference you quoted does not explicitly contain any caution to completion's use,  2/ as completion is a block it could be executed even if the SKNode it is attached has been removed from the scene and 3/ this does not explain the behavior described in this question.

Comment: 1. You're right, Apple could add a note to the documentation describing this behavior. It would be helpful even though it is pretty intuitive. 2. Why would you expect the _completion_ block for an `SKAction` to be called if said `SKAction` never successfully _completed_. 3. It explains exactly why the completion block isn't called, which is the behavior your describe in the question. I'd love to hear why you think this answer doesn't explain the behavior.

Comment: My question is maybe not well written: sorry for that. Thank you for taking time to answering me. In the question, the completion block isn't call in one case, the second one, when  `removeFromParent` action is placed before the remove from `theGrid` action. In the other it is called as following your explanations it should not be executed at all. As written in the documentation, completion block is called *"when the actions completed"*.

Comment: "completion block is called _when the actions completed_." It didn't complete in the second one, where you put `removeFromParent` before the remove from `theGrid` action. I don't know how much clearer I can be :(

Comment: Remove from parent is causing the rest of the actions in the sequence not to be called, since `theSprite` is no longer in the scene. The sequence didn't complete, therefore the completion block shouldn't be called. It's a completion block, not a result block where you'd get a success/fail status. Completion block is logically only called on a successful completion.

Comment: Ok, I know understand what really happen. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79515/discussion-between-domsware-and-ben-kane).