# In which cases runAction on SKNode does not complete?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Are there any known cases where running an `SKAction` using `runAction` does not complete?

I launch several 'runAction' on different `SKNode`. In order to synchronize all these actions, I use a counter that is incremented inside the completion block of each `SKAction`. When the counter reach the exact number of launched `SKAction` then the animations is completed.

From time to time one `SKAction` does not complete then the animation never complete.

```
// Several actions are launched...
myNode.runAction(myActions,completion:{

    checkCompletion()

})



// Check if all actions completed
//
// numberOfLaunchedActions: number of actions launched
// logDebug: some log helper
func checkCompletion() {

    // This counter is initialized earlier
    numberOfCompletedActions++

    logDebug(">> Actions completed: \(numberOfCompletedActions)/\(numberOfLaunchedActions)")

    if numberOfCompletedActions == numberOfLaunchedActions {
        /// some statements
         logDebug("Animation Completed!")
    }

}
```

Actions are dynamically generated and are composed of `sequence` of following actions:

- `waitForDuration`
- `scaleTo`
- `moveBy`
- `hide`
- `unhide`

No `removeFromParent` nor `runAction` nor `runBlock`.

The action I focus my attention on is the following:

```
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.4)

let scaleAction = SKAction.scaleTo(0.1, duration: 2.0)
scaleAction.timingMode = .EaseOut

let myAction = SKAction.sequence([
    waitAction,
    scaleAction,
])
```

Comment: I have not run into this. Are you able to provide a code snippet? Asking if there are any known cases makes it hard to answer. As to why yours isn't finishing could be easier to figure out then a general has anyone had this issue.

Comment: Posting code would be helpful. Other than explicitly removing the action, one thing that can cause an action to stop is if you remove the node from the scene in the middle of a sequence, like what happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599078/skaction-runaction-does-not-execute-completion-block/30600553#30600553). Maybe you did something similar. Hard to say without seeing code.

Comment: No code... no answer.

Comment: @Domsware This code don't says much because the "heart" of the problem is in the myActions...Can you please update your question with that part of code (where you creating myActions variable) ?

Comment: I am confused on what checkCompletion() does. I see it logging stuff out but is it suppose to rerun the action if it isn't equal?

Comment: `checkCompletion()` count the number of completed actions. When all actions are completed it does some statements I do not put in there for clarity purposes.

Comment: @Ben Kane, no node is removed in the middle of the sequence. I wait all actions complete to do such operations.

Comment: Ok back to the original question. You stated that the animation never completes. Are you not seeing a log in the checkCompletion method and that is what your are referring to?

Comment: My gut says it is working correctly but you are expecting a different result. Without the real code I am unable to help identify it. Best I can do is recommended you double check where you log what and validate that what you think should happen matches the actual code written. I suspect it is a simple matter of either a race condition or shared variable you are manipulating.

Comment: Log does not appear, that's correct. But the program is blocked, waiting for the completion of an action. Log is only a visual help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80233/discussion-between-domsware-and-skyler-lauren).

Answer (score 0):

There is one known case: adding action after `Remove from parent` in a `sequence`: [SKAction runAction does not execute completion block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30599078/540780)

As explained in comment:

> `Remove from parent` is causing the rest of the actions in the
>   `sequence` not to be called, since the involved node is no longer in
>   the scene. The sequence didn't complete, therefore the completion
>   block shouldn't be called.

Comment: Are you saying that was your issue here as well?

Comment: @BenKane No. You helped me to solve a problem : in this case it's another problem.